# increase efficiency of pandas groupby with custom aggregation function

Tags: python, pandas, performance, aggregation

I have a not so large dataframe (somewhere in `2000x10000` range in terms of shape).

I am trying to `groupby` a columns, and average the first N non-null entries:

e.g.

```
def my_part_of_interest(v,N=42):
   valid=v[~np.isnan(v)]
   return np.mean(valid.values[0:N])

mydf.groupby('key').agg(my_part_of_interest)
```

It now take a long time (dozen of minutes), when `.agg(np.nanmean)`
 was instead in order of seconds.

how to get it running faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things to consider:

1. Droping the nan entries on the entire df via single operation is faster than doing it on chunks of grouped datasets `mydf.dropna(subset=['v'], inplace=True)`
2. Use the .head to slice `mydf.groupby('key').apply(lambda x: x.head(42).agg('mean')`

I think those combined can optimize things a bit and they are more idiomatic to pandas.